# Configuring FHIR OSS to use a specific database name

Tags: deployment, fhir-server-for-azure

I am deploying the Microsoft Open Source FHIR server to Azure using the supplied ARM templates (which I have converted to BICEP templates).

I want to deploy a test instance and a prod instance (in different resource groups), but I would like them to use the same cosmosdb account (which is in a 3rd resource group).
Whilst you can point a deployment to use an existing cosmosdb account, presumably the database names would clash.
In principle this seems possible if you could configure the name of the database to be used by a deployment.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Many thanks,
Andreas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the loop on this, this can be done by supplying the following configuration setting: `CosmosDb__DatabaseId`

You can set the corresponding value to a database name of your choice.